# How to stretch width of hyperlink (a) tag to full width

Tags: html, css

I need to fix the width of `a` tag. It should be aligned with `li` tag. If `li` tag has 100 % of width `a` tag should follow the `li` with 100% of width.

Please see the code.

```css
li{background:#ff0000; width:100%}
a{background:#ccc; width:100%}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
 <li class="page_item page-item-12 current_page_ancestor current_page_parent has_children">
  <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/">HTML5</a>
  <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
   <li class="page_item page-item-62 current_page_item">
    <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html5-tutorial/" aria-current="page">HTML5 Tutorial</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-64"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-tutorial/">HTML Tutorial</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-66"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-forms/">HTML Forms</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-68"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-graphics/">HTML Graphics</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-70"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-apis/">HTML APIs</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-72"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-example/">HTML Example</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-74"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-references/">HTML References</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display:block` to your `li` and `a` otherwise `width: 100%` has no effect on inline elements.

```css
li{background:#ff0000; width:100%; display: block}
a{background:#ccc; width:100%; display: block}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
 <li class="page_item page-item-12 current_page_ancestor current_page_parent has_children">
  <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/">HTML5</a>
  <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
   <li class="page_item page-item-62 current_page_item">
    <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html5-tutorial/" aria-current="page">HTML5 Tutorial</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-64"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-tutorial/">HTML Tutorial</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-66"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-forms/">HTML Forms</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-68"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-graphics/">HTML Graphics</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-70"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-apis/">HTML APIs</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-72"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-example/">HTML Example</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-74"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-references/">HTML References</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this `CSS` `display:block` for `a` `tag`

```css
li{background:#ff0000; width:100%}
a{background:#ccc; width:100%; display:block}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-sidebar-menu">
 <li class="page_item page-item-12 current_page_ancestor current_page_parent has_children">
  <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/">HTML5</a>
  <ul class="child-sidebar-menu">
   <li class="page_item page-item-62 current_page_item">
    <a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html5-tutorial/" aria-current="page">HTML5 Tutorial</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-64"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-tutorial/">HTML Tutorial</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-66"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-forms/">HTML Forms</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-68"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-graphics/">HTML Graphics</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-70"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-apis/">HTML APIs</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-72"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-example/">HTML Example</a></li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-74"><a href="http://localhost/html5beta/html5/html-references/">HTML References</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```